# Writing a function to create columns based on below conditions

Tags: r

I have the following example data, where purchase is always >=date_conception.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  purchase = c("2023-01-01", "2023-05-30", "2023-09-06", "2023-08-26"),  # Example start weeks for each person
  date_conception = c("2023-01-01", "2023-05-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-07-01"),  # Minimum start week for each person
  treatement_length = c(30, 45, 20, 10))%>%
  mutate(date_conception = as.Date(date_conception),
         purchase = as.Date(purchase))%>%
  mutate(trimestre_1 = date_conception + days(98))
```

Basically women take medications (purchase) somewhere between first day of conception (date_conception) until the end of first trimester (trimestre_1) making them vulnerable for 14 weeks. I am trying to see when women take the medication and for how long in these 14 weeks only. Say a woman started her medication (purchase) on the first day of conception (date_conception) and her prescription is for 30 days. This means she is exposed for 5 weeks starting from week1 (7days/wk + 2 days for the 5th week). Therefore I want to create a function where I create 5 columns (wk 1 - wk5) that are populated with the number of days of expoure. So wk1 - wk4 cells have the number 7 and wk5 has the number 2. The rest of columns from 6-14 have zeros.

Another example is if a woman purchases a medication with 10 day prescription a day before  the end of week 14. This means she has number 1 on week 14 and rest of the previous weeks have zeros.

If a woman is exposed on week 7 for 20 days, previous weeks have zeros and weeks 7-8 are populated by the number 7, week9 with number 6 and weeks 10-14 have zeros  etc. The cells need to be populated by the number of days exposed to a treatment (max 7 days of exposure per week and the remainder of prescription goes on to other weeks until it reaches zero).

I tried something like this but it isn't correct:

```
create_week_columns <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(
      adjusted_start_week = pmax(start_week, minimum_start_week), 
      week1  = pmin(pmax(8 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(number_of_days, 7)),
      week2  = pmin(pmax(15 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 7, 0), 7)),
      week3  = pmin(pmax(22 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 14, 0), 7)),
      week4  = pmin(pmax(29 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 21, 0), 7)),
      week5  = pmin(pmax(36 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 28, 0), 7)),
      week6  = pmin(pmax(43 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 35, 0), 7)),
      week7  = pmin(pmax(50 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 42, 0), 7)),
      week8  = pmin(pmax(57 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 49, 0), 7)),
      week9  = pmin(pmax(64 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 56, 0), 7)),
      week10 = pmin(pmax(71 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 63, 0), 7)),
      week11 = pmin(pmax(78 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 70, 0), 7)),
      week12 = pmin(pmax(85 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 77, 0), 7)),
      week13 = pmin(pmax(92 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 84, 0), 7)),
      week14 = pmin(pmax(99 - adjusted_start_week, 0), pmin(pmax(number_of_days - 91, 0), 7)),
      week15 = pmax(number_of_days - 98, 0)
    ) %>%
    select(-adjusted_start_week, -week15) %>%  # Drop the intermediate column
    ungroup()  # Don't forget to ungroup to restore the default behavior
}

result_df <- create_week_columns(df)
```

The desired output is :

```
result_df <- df%>%
  mutate(week1 = c(7, 0, 0, 0),
         week2 = c(7,0,0,0),
         week3 = c(7,0,0,0),
         week4 = c(7,0,0,0),
         week5 = c(2,7,0,0),
         week6 = c(0,7,0,0),
         week7 = c(0,7,0,0),
         week8 = c(0,7,0,0),
         week9 = c(0,7,0,7),
         week10 = c(0,7,0,3),
         week11 = c(0,3,0,0),
         week12 = c(0,0,0,0),
         week13 = c(0,0,0,0),
         week14 = c(0,0,2,0),
         week15 = c(0,0,18,0)) # week15 is to be dropped from any further analysis, but just to show how the output would look like. We could create more columns to have 7's until we reach zero. But I am dropping columns after week 14 from analysis.
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your desired output?

Comment: We can code this. However, what is your overall goal? To me it sounds a bit like a https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @nightstand of course! I just updated my question with the desired output

Comment: @Friede I am trying to see temporal use of medications. Other variables are in the original dataset. I have a dose associated with the medication and I am trying to see the cumulative dose a woman is exposed to every week in those 14 weeks. Needless to say, weeks with 7's would result with women taking the same same cumulative dose, but with less than 7, the cumulative dose for that week is different. Also, identifying the week of exposure is important for biological reasons.

Comment: This looks like an xy problem to me, as pointed out by Friede. Please elaborate a little more about the need to distribute the days accross fixed  week bins. If we want to know how many full weeks and days in the last week from a integer value, `\(x) list(nweeks = floor(x/7), ndays = x %% 7)` will do the trick, you can pick up from that.

Comment: @GuedesBF Hi thanks for the answer! I fail to see how this is a xy problem. Maybe I am not clear enough with my explanation. I am trying to see for how many days a week (over 14 weeks) a woman was exposed to a specific medication for malformation outcome. Given a woman cannot be exposed more than 7 days/week, this means her max exposure days per week is 7. If a woman has a prescription with 10-day duration, this means she was exposed for a whole week + 3 days in the next week i.e exposure varies per week. Added problem is that they have different starting exposure period (week1 or 2, 3 to 14).

Comment: Could you re-check the results for rows 2 & 3?

Comment: @margusl I have an extra layer of complexity to add to my question. Your code answers my original question. However, I was wondering the following. In some cases, women buy a medication during week 1 before their prescription is complet. So when I run your code, I have women with overlapping periods. so wk 1 and wk 2 overlap with a few days. I am wondering if it would be possible to remove the overlap period and add it to the end of wk 2 in case we have less than 7 or to wk 3 in case wk 2 is filled with 7. I want to report those days to another week with less than 7 but not surpass wk 14.

Comment: Shifting subsequent purchase -- treatment_length periods by a number of overlap days seems bit easier than removing and adding periods. Though it also sounds like a new / follow-up question, if you choose to go for a follow-up Q, you can include a link to this one to provide some more context for others.

Comment: @margusl Hey ! I read about shifting the new date by the number of overlap yesterday. I saw a sas code that did this and I've been trying to replicate it, but kind of failing miserably. I do not know if you could help me with it, please ? The paper in question is this one: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/forum2007/043-2007.pdf 
I will definitely modify the question and add all the answers to it once it is completed ! I think other R users could benefit from this for sure. The paper I provided explains/summarizes perfectly what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lubridate intervals for fun and profit.
We'll create a helper function `exposure_days_by_week()` that splits the interval from `date_conception` to `trimestre_1` into a vector of 14 7-day intervals (each defined by its start and end date-times) and finds intersections between each of those and the exposure interval, in days.

From `exposure_days_by_week()` outputs we'll create a list column; once it's unnested, we'll have variables with a number of exposed days for each 7-day interval.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

exposure_days_by_week <- function(conception_date, purchase_date, treatment_len_days, weeks = 14){
  # vector of vulnerable weeks as Lubridate Intervals, length 14
  int_vuln_weeks <- 
    # first interval, starts with conception_date, duration: 1 week
    as.interval(dweeks(1), start = conception_date) %>% 
    # shift first interval by 0:(14-1) to create a vector of 14,
    # 0:(weeks-1): we want to keep 1st week interval where it currently is 
    int_shift(by = dweeks(0:(weeks-1)))
  # treatment interval, starts with conception_date, duration: treatment_len_days
  int_treatment <-  
    as.interval(ddays(treatment_len_days), start = purchase_date)
  # find intersections of intervals, divide by 1 day to get
  # intersection durations in days; non-intersecting weeks are returned as NA's,
  # replace those with 0
  (intersect(int_vuln_weeks, int_treatment) / ddays(1)) %>% replace_na(0)
}


result_df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  # exposure_days_by_week returns vector of length 14, store those in a
  # a list-column and then unnest
  mutate(week = exposure_days_by_week(date_conception, purchase, treatement_length) %>% list()) %>% 
  unnest_wider(week, names_sep = "")
```

Result:

```r
result_df %>% 
  rename_with(abbreviate, minlength = 5)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 19
#>      id prchs      dt_cn      trtm_ trm_1      week1 week2 week3 week4 week5
#>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 2023-01-01 2023-01-01    30 2023-04-09     7     7     7     7     2
#> 2     2 2023-05-30 2023-05-01    45 2023-08-07     0     0     0     0     6
#> 3     3 2023-09-06 2023-06-01    20 2023-09-07     0     0     0     0     0
#> 4     4 2023-08-26 2023-07-01    10 2023-10-07     0     0     0     0     0
#> # ℹ 9 more variables: week6 <dbl>, week7 <dbl>, week8 <dbl>, week9 <dbl>,
#> #   wek10 <dbl>, wek11 <dbl>, wek12 <dbl>, wek13 <dbl>, wek14 <dbl>

glimpse(result_df)
#> Rows: 4
#> Columns: 19
#> $ id                <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4
#> $ purchase          <date> 2023-01-01, 2023-05-30, 2023-09-06, 2023-08-26
#> $ date_conception   <date> 2023-01-01, 2023-05-01, 2023-06-01, 2023-07-01
#> $ treatement_length <dbl> 30, 45, 20, 10
#> $ trimestre_1       <date> 2023-04-09, 2023-08-07, 2023-09-07, 2023-10-07
#> $ week1             <dbl> 7, 0, 0, 0
#> $ week2             <dbl> 7, 0, 0, 0
#> $ week3             <dbl> 7, 0, 0, 0
#> $ week4             <dbl> 7, 0, 0, 0
#> $ week5             <dbl> 2, 6, 0, 0
#> $ week6             <dbl> 0, 7, 0, 0
#> $ week7             <dbl> 0, 7, 0, 0
#> $ week8             <dbl> 0, 7, 0, 0
#> $ week9             <dbl> 0, 7, 0, 7
#> $ week10            <dbl> 0, 7, 0, 3
#> $ week11            <dbl> 0, 4, 0, 0
#> $ week12            <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0
#> $ week13            <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0
#> $ week14            <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 0
```

Input data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  purchase = c("2023-01-01", "2023-05-30", "2023-09-06", "2023-08-26"),
  date_conception = c("2023-01-01", "2023-05-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-07-01"),
  treatement_length = c(30, 45, 20, 10))%>%
  mutate(date_conception = as.Date(date_conception),
         purchase = as.Date(purchase))%>%
  mutate(trimestre_1 = date_conception + days(98))
```

Comment: This works like magic! Thanks a lot for taking the time